# Python backports.configparser not found, impacting both conda and pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda

I was having trouble with the pandas numpy dependencies, and decided it was a reasonable idea to uninstall and re-install both modules with use of the pip tool. Unfortunately, that decision was the wrong one as it has caused another problem. When issuing the 'conda' or 'pip' commands, both fail with the following stack trace, indicating that backports.configparser does not exist.

```
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\gdeemer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\gdeemer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\gdeemer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\gdeemer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\gdeemer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
  File "C:\Users\gdeemer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 11, in <module>
    from distutils.command.install import SCHEME_KEYS  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils.core import Command
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\core.py", line 18, in <module>
    from distutils.config import PyPIRCCommand
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\config.py", line 7, in <module>
    from configparser import RawConfigParser
  File "C:\Users\gdeemer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\configparser.py", line 11, in <module>
    from backports.configparser import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backports.configparser'
```

Any ideas on how I can get this resolved? I'm also a Spyder user, which is no longer opening either.

Comment: It shows you have a separate install of Python (`AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftware...`). Running Conda commands should not hit other interpreter installs, so make sure your `PATH` doesn't include that.

Comment: @merv thanks for pointing that out. I removed the \Local\Packages\PythonSoftware from the PATH and have the conda/pip functionality working. I'll have to reinstall a number of modules that had once been cross-reference to Local, but that should be a simple fix.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback and glad that was helpful. I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Conda is quite fragile to violations of the isolation it so carefully tries to establish. In this case, the output shows a separate install of Python

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0
```

and an associated `site-packages`

```
AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0
```

Ensure that these are not on the `PATH` (or `PYTHONPATH`) when running Conda commands, otherwise they could be interfering with Conda's functionality.